# Golang: remove entry from a map[interface{}]interface{} unmarshalled from YAML

Tags: go, yaml

I'm working on writing some tests where I need to check different error conditions when loading the application config from a YAML file. As the YAML file is quite long, my approach is to read the full YAML content from the file on disk, unmarshall its content to a variable, dynamically remove some section/s from the generated `map[interface{}]interface{}` based on their string keys, and finally marshall it and write the content to a different file on disk that will be used as the text input. That said, I'm facing issues when trying to remove sections from the unmarshalled yaml. Below is my code:

```golang
func getYAMLWithoutSection(t *testing.T, section string) map[interface{}]interface{} {
    t.Helper()

    yml := unmarshalYAML(t, getYAMLContentFromFile(t))
    var tmp interface{}
    tmp = yml

    keys := strings.Split(section, ".")
    for _, key := range keys {
        tmp = tmp.(map[interface{}]interface{})[key]
    }

    tmp = nil

    return yml
}

// Reads file from disk and returns its content
func getYAMLContentFromFile(t *testing.T) []byte {
    /* ... */
}

func unmarshalYAML(t *testing.T, ymlIn []byte) map[interface{}]interface{} {
    /* ... */
}
```

This doesn't work because at the end of the day, the `tmp` var contains the value of the targeted YAML section instead of its memory address (its type is `interface{}`, not a pointer), so when I set it to `nil` it has no effect over the value in the original `yml` variable that it finally returns. I've tried different things like switching the type of `tmp` to `*interface{}`, but with no success, and I can't figure out what would be the proper way of doing this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally found the way of achieving what I was looking for (dynamically editing the nested map that contains the unmarshalled YAML). This is how my code looks like now:

```golang
func getYAMLWithoutSection(t *testing.T, section string) map[interface{}]interface{} {
    t.Helper()

    yml := unmarshalYAML(t, getConfigFileContent(t))
    tmp := yml

    keys := strings.Split(section, ".")
    nKeys := len(keys) - 1
    for i, key := range keys {
        if i == nKeys {
            tmp[key] = nil
            break
        }

        tmp = tmp[key].(map[interface{}]interface{})
    }

    return yml
}
```

The thing is in the original version (the one I posted in my question) I was using a `tmp` variable with type `interface{}` so every time I assign a submap to this variable, its content is copied to it and removing keys (or modifying their values) on this variable has no effect over the original `yml` one. However, in this version I switch `tmp` to a map `map[interface{}]interface{}`, and taking into account that in Go maps are reference types, every modification on this variable is actually reflected on the `tmp` one.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the value into a variable and then setting that variable to nil. That won't modify the map only the variable.

Depending on how you want to modify the map, when you're on the last iteration while ranging over `keys` you can either:

```
m := tmp.(map[interface{}]interface{})
m[key] = nil
```

or

```
m := tmp.(map[interface{}]interface{})
delete(m, key)
```

The first approach will leave the key in the map but the value will be nil. The second approach removes the key from the map.

https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/22

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you for your reply. I think you're describing the root cause of the issue and it actually is what I say in my question but with other words (probably better phrased). However, I think that you aren't proposing a solution. I mean, I need the tmp variable to traverse the map until I reach the nested map that contains the desired key, and I haven't been able to do that on the original map or storing a pointer to the nested maps instead of their values in the `tmp` variable (it cannot be of type `*inteface{}`, that doesn`t work).

Comment: So you tell me I don't propose an answer just to post a new answer using everything I describe in my answer?

Comment: I'm sorry Corey if you get me wrong... What I mean is that in your reply you point out the root cause of the issue, which is something that I commented in my question (you can take a look), but you don't say how to avoid storing the value instead of a reference to it. I tried your version and it doesn't work, you're actually proposing the same I originally have but in two steps instead of one, so that doesn't fix the issue. What makes the trick is to switch the type of the `tmp` variable from `interface{}` to `map[interface{}]interface{}`, and that's something you don't mention :)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: btw, I voted your reply up to give you some credit (before you posted your reply to my comment). So I don't think I did it so wrong. Did I?

Comment: You can't get a reference to something inside a map. It's unaddressable by design. I don't mention that you need to switch the type of `tmp`? I literally do it twice in my answer. I'm sorry I didn't hand you something you could cut and paste.

Comment: Well, think what you want man. Just one thing, your sarcasm won't give you any gold badge ;)

Comment: Of course not, but accurately answering questions has garnered me 31 of them.

Comment: Yeah, and there is one that you deserve but haven't been granted... Enjoy your badges and your ego ;)